# Copy files from s3 bucket to azure blob storage in airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

My task is to Copy files from s3 bucket to azure blob storage in airflow.
I found using **azcopy** i can move my data from s3 bucket to azure blob storage but the problem is i have to create dag for this which should trigger daily on specific time.

i have write and read permission for particular container of client machine (azure blob storage).

client has provided few details of blob storage

**AccountName  : "xxx"
Container Name  : "xxx"
Blob SAS URL  : "xxx"
Blob SAS Token  : "xxx"
Storage account key  : "xxx"**

Can someone please help me to create airflow dag which can copy or move data from s3 bucket to azure blob storage

Answer (score 0):

You can use rclone. You must set schedule time slices.
(Windows:Task scheduler Linux:Cron)

Comment: rclone command copies data from the source Azure Blob container to the destination S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Skyplane](https://github.com/skyplane-project/skyplane) to copy data across clouds. To transfer from S3 to Azure blob storage you can call the command:

```
skyplane cp -r s3://aws-bucket-name/ az://azure-bucket-name/
```